# Properly parallelizing pyspark text analysis app

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing

**tl;dr I fixed my code by increasing the number of partitions to equal the number of files but don't understand why this worked or if it was the best approach. Any input is appreciated.**

I've been trying to parallelize a process via `SparkConf` but this usually results in a memory overhead error (exceeding 5GB default allocation). The fix was to set `spark.default.parallelism` to 690 (100 GBs from 690 separate files in S3).

- Shouldn't each executor be able to handle more than one file at a time?

The function `process_files` is composed of:

1. download text file from S3
2. count instances of a word
3. yield count along with other metadata

```py
def run():
    '''docstring for run'''
    conf = SparkConf() \
        .set("spark.default.parallelism", 690)
    sc = SparkContext(
        appName='spark-cc-analysis',
        conf=conf)
    sqlc = SQLContext(sparkContext=sc)

    filename = config.input_file
    pathlist = pathlist_from_csv(filename)

    rdd = sc.parallelize(pathlist)
    results = rdd.mapPartitions(process_files).collect()

    columns = ['file_name','timestamp','entity','entity_count']
    df = sqlc.createDataFrame(results,columns)
    df.show()
    output = config.output
    df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(output)
```

**memory overhead error that occurs when parallelism set to 100**

```
WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Requesting driver to remove executor 13 for 
reason Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits.  5.1 GB of 5.0 GB physical memory 
used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead or disabling yarn.nodemanager.vmem-
check-enabled because of YARN-4714.
```

Answer (score 1):

This all depends on the size of your files and the operations you're mapping. No one here is going to be able to tell you why your executor is using as much memory as it's using.

You're going to have to go through the tough job of debugging resource consumption on your executors through log analysis. Or if cost is no object you can just increase the memory and not worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By increase memory are you referring to the memoryOverhead mentioned in the error message above or simply the memory of each node on the cluster?

Comment: memoryOverhead is just the configuration variable that you can adjust to allocate more memory to the executor. Depending on what underlying infrastructure you're using for your cluster, you may need to increase actual physical memory as well.